# Django, m2m_changed в методе save

Tags: python, django, парсер

**Django**. Есть ли возможность сохранить запись в методе `save`?
То есть, метод `save` в моделях у меня парсит данные с онлайн кинотеатра. Но у меня есть поле `m2m`(Жанры) и перед тем, как добавить жанры к записи, запись нужно сохранить, что бы у записи была `ID`. Я так понимаю, что нужно использовать `m2m_changed`, но как использовать этот сигнал понять не могу.

```
class Genre(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Жанр', blank=True)


class Trailer(models.Model):
    film_url = models.URLField('Ссылка на фильм')
    genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre, verbose_name='Жанры', blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        source = requests.get(self.film_url).text
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')

        parser_genres = soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'video-genre'})
        for genres in parser_genres:
            genre = Genre.objects.get_or_create(title=genres.text)[0]
            genre.save()
            self.genre.add(genre.id)
```

Данный код дает ошибку `ValueError`, говорит что, перед тем как добавить данные в `m2m` у записи должна быть `ID`:

`"<Trailer: Мстители: Финал>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.`

Answer (score 1):

Сперва нужно сохранить `Trailer`. Уберите ваш код который переопределяет метод `save`.
Далее можно использовать сигнал `post_save`, а именно:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender= Trailer)
def add_genre(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    source = requests.get(instance.film_url).text
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')

    parser_genres = soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'video-genre'})
    temp = set()
    for genres in parser_genres:
        genre, _ = Genre.objects.get_or_create(title=genres.text)
        temp.add(genre)
    instance.genre.add(*temp)
```

Comment: Все так же, жанры создаются, но не добавляются.

Comment: Я так понимаю, `instance` нужно сохранять, но `instance.save()` вызывает рекурсию.

Comment: Уберите весь ваш код который переопределяет метод `save` вашей модели. Далее после того как вы в вашем коде выполните `instance.save()`, либо же сохраните данные через админку, сработает сигнал и так как это `post_save` то и сработает он непосредственно после сохранения трейлера.

Comment: Выполнять `instance.save()` в `add_genre` не нужно

Comment: Тогда в `m2m` нечего не записывается. `save` Метод удалил. Похоже именно с `m2m` случается баг.